# REST api request

Tags: java, rest

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.population.population.estimator.model.Country;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class PopulationService {

public void getPopulation() {
String query_url = "https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=world-population%40kapsarc&facet=country_name&facet=year&refine.country_name=Australia&refine.year=2000";

try {
            URL url = new URL(query_url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(25000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
}  catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    getPopulation();
  }
}
```

Following is the output showing exception details.

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=world-population%40kapsarc&facet=country_name&facet=year&refine.country_name=Australia&refine.year=2000

Stack Trace:

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.population.population.estimator.service.PopulationService.getPopulation(PopulationService.java:55)
    at org.population.population.estimator.resources.PopulationResource.getPopulation(PopulationResource.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=world-population%40kapsarc&facet=country_name&facet=year&refine.country_name=Australia&refine.year=2000
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.population.population.estimator.service.PopulationService.getPopulation(PopulationService.java:52)
    ... 48 more
```

just placing the query in the browser returns a response but through my program, I get an error. If someone can hellp I would be grateful.

Im creating a rest service

Comment: Can you attach the exception stack trace...

Comment: You need to find the exact error message that api is sending in the response. You can modify your code to get the message from the error stream like so: `HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection; InputStream is; if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) { is = httpConn.getErrorStream(); } else { is = httpConn.getInputStream(); }`

Comment: Remove  `OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();`. There's no reason to open an OutputStream since you don't want to send anything. Removing it solved the issue. Setting the content type is also useless (and wrong): a GET request doesn't have any content, so it doesn't have any content type.

Comment: Thanks for tolerating my, uh, newbiness. This was terrific, thank you for your time.

Comment: @wuiiz93 This Java API is absolutely horrible. The names are awful, the methods are unintuitive. If you really need to write many such methods, I would look into using a more modern HTTP client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use InputStream since you are reading data from the response. Second, you have to accept as json response for that you have to use `conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");`

I have modified your program, please check.

```
public class PopulationService {

  public static void getPopulation() {
    String query_url =
        "https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=world-population@kapsarc&facet=country_name&facet=year&refine.country_name=Australia&refine.year=2000";

    try {
      URL url = new URL(query_url);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.connect();

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              (conn.getInputStream())));
      String output;
      System.out.println("Response Server .... \n");
      while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
      }
      conn.disconnect();

      int status = conn.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("Status Code: "+status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    getPopulation();
  }
}
```